# Update multiple values, in different columns, to null based on what the value is intitially in Mysql

Tags: mysql

There are different date columns in a table and some rows in the table have 1st of January values, "YYYY-01-01".

I can do a query and find all those rows with any date field that has 1st Jan YYYY.

```
select * from table 
where dob like '%01-01' 
OR start_date like '%01-01'
OR ...
```

But how do I then set those values to NULL?

I've tried:

```
update table 
set dob = NULL
where dob='%01-01';
update table 
set start_date= NULL
where start_date='%01-01';
...
```

That doesn't work...

Comment: Why use "LIKE" in one part of the problem and "equals" in the other !?!

Comment: Was that the mistake? Oh dear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this:

```
UPDATE table SET dob = null WHERE dob LIKE '%01-01'
```

EDIT: corrected

Answer (score 1):

Use `update`:

```
update table
    set start_date = NULL
    where day(start_date) = 1 and month(start_date) = 1;

update table
    set dob = NULL
    where day(dob) = 1 and day(dob) = 1;
```

You might as well do a separate update for each column.  Although the logic can be encapsulated into a single query, that is just a more complicated query.

Don't use `like` on dates.  `like` is for *strings*.  MySQL has plenty of appropriate date functions.

Do note:  Some people really are born on January 1st.